# Getting Worker data from Jobs with Pthread/PHP

Tags: php, pthreads

I construct a Pool with a TermWorker class with Pthread and PHP 7. I select several terms from a Database source, and I want to process it with specific Jobs. This is my code, for doing this:

```
//index.php
$termpool = new Pool(1, TermWorker::class);
foreach($terms as $term) {
$termpool->submit(new PostagJob(["termArray" => $termArray, "lamachinePath" => $lamachine_path]));
$termpool->submit(new ClassifyJob($termArray));
}
```

In the PostagJob I want to save data to the worker,
I use a array merge for this, and I'm setting a status, see:

```
//PostagJob.php
public function run() {
 $this->worker->postag_labels = array_merge(
 $this->worker->postag_labels,
 //Prevent Volatile object, cast to array
 (array)[
  "word" => $word_key,
  "label" => $word["pos"]["@attributes"]["head"],
  "lemma" => $word["pos"]["@attributes"]["class"]
 ]);
 $this->worker->postag_status = "Tagged";
}
```

In another Job named ClassifyJob, I do several classifications,
but I also want to use the saved postag_labels (from the worker).
Currently I'm using a while loop for checking the data:

```
//ClassifyJob.php
public function run() {
 while(true) {
 //Postag labels are available
  if($this->worker->postag_status === "Tagged") {
   print_r($this->worker->postag_labels); 
   break;
  } else if($this->worker->postag_status === "Untaggable") {
   //Not possible, to classify this way
   break;
  }
 }
}
```

I notice that the data is not being printed, and that it keeps waiting/looping.
How can I retreive the data from the worker in the ClassifyJob?
I saw `synchronized()`, `wait()` and `join()`, is that what I need?
How can I implement this, or what else do I need to do?

Edit: My full code is on this Github repo: https://github.com/KSART-nl/terma.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bit of a misunderstanding with respect to how arrays are treated in pthreads, as well as some problems with the immutability semantics of pthreads.

Arrays are casted to `Volatile` objects when they are assigned to properties of `Threaded` objects. This means that the `(array)` cast inside of the `array_merge` call is not needed. Given that an array is returned from `array_merge`, if you wish to keep the result as an array (which I suspect you do), then that's when you should be explicitly casting to an array.

Looking at your `PostagJob::__construct` method, you are not casting the `termArray` of `$payload` to be an array, and so it will become a `Volatile` object. This is problematic because it will error out when used inside of `array_merge` later on.

But your code should not even make it that far, because inside of your `TermWorker` class, you are initialising the `postag_labels` property to be an empty array. Remember that arrays are casted to `Volatile` objects on `Threaded` objects (which `Worker` extends). This means that the property is a `Volatile` object of a `Threaded` class, making it immutable. And so when you attempt to initialise a new `PostagJob` object, it should fail with an immutability violation error. Removing the property initialisation to an array and performing the aforementioned cast (in the previous paragraph) should resolve this issue.

So in order for this to work, you must stay with using arrays, which means using explicit casting whenever an array is assigned to a property of a `Threaded` object.

Try fixing the above problems and then let me know if something still doesn't work. (Updating your original post with a smaller, reproducing example of your problem would be much appreciated, since trudging through a codebase takes too much time.)